# Building a hybrid app with an integrated audiostream - will it play? [HTML5 Hybrid App]

Tags: html, audio-streaming, hybrid-mobile-app

So I am building this hybrid app and I want to integrate playing an audio stream. I could build this funcion into the native wrapper (the container app) or I could just make a separate page for my player and use the HTML5 Audio tag to play the stream.

Question is: If I use the audio tag, will the music stop playing if the screen goes to powersave? Can the native code wrapper (container) of the hybrid app keep the stream playing, if I use the audio tag on an HTML5 page rendered by the browser (inside the hybrid wrap)?

Comment: Preliminary test: Stream is played, even when screen goes to powersave and if app (wrapper) is minimized. 

If f.inst. a browser is opened (and takes the foreground) the stream shuts off after a short while.

This is only tested on Android.

iOS test coming up.

It seems to be possible, if we spend more time on it - programming the wrapper to stay active and run in background. It might be really simple.

Comment: Got it working. Plays in background, while using browser or other apps. Keeps playing with only minor quirks. It is doable and these references may be of help: - http://www.serversideup.net/programming/style-the-html-5-audio-element
- http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/site-elements/create-a-customised-html5-audio-player/

Possible framework for custom controls: http://jplayer.org/